# Amazon EC2 - Adding a Elastic IP does not show up in IIS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, amazon-elastic-ip

I have created a Windows Server 2012 EC2 instance and I have bound an Elastic IP address to the server.  The problem is, the IP address isn't showing up in IIS 8 and I can't seem to get web sites to respond if I manually type in the IP address.

How can I get IIS to recognize the IP address and respond on that?  I am about to connect to the server via RDP via the elastic ip so I know it is bound to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Elastic IPs are forwarded to the private IP you choose and for the most of it the server doesn't know what it's public IP address is. It's available at metadata if you really need it.

You should bind IIS to the private IP address.

Assuming you have Elastic IP 1.1.1.1 bound to 10.0.0.10 you should setup in IIS the 10.0.0.10 (or just bind to all addresses).

Comment: Thanks for that!  What happens if I want to add multiple SSL certificates and they require a seperate ip address each?

Comment: I haven't used IIS in a while but you have two choices:
- One that works is if you only need a few SSL certificates (there is a limit that depends on the instance size at AWS) is to have a private IP address for each of the SSL sites;
- The second one, isn't compatible with older browsers/OS, is to use SNI (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx). I've never used this at IIS but works well on nginx/apache.